# SAML Authorization with renewal of assertion

Tags: authentication, authorization, saml-2.0

I am trying to add the authorization in SAML as part of IDP implementation using [SAML 2.0 Bearer Assertion Profiles for OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521)

Here, the SAML assertion is exchanged for Oauth2 access token. As per specs, the only access token should be returned in exchange of the SAML assertion and refresh token should not be returned. Following is mentioned in the spec regarding renewal of the access token (RFC7521)

> An assertion used in this context is generally a short-lived
> representation of the authorization grant, and authorization servers
> SHOULD NOT issue access tokens with a lifetime that exceeds the validity period of the assertion by a significant period.  In practice, that will usually mean that refresh tokens are not issued in response to assertion grant requests, and access tokens will be issued with a reasonably short lifetime.  Clients can refresh an expired access token by requesting a new one using the same assertion, if it is still valid, or with a new assertion.

Now, if the access token is expired client can get new access token in exchange of assertion if the Assertion is still valid but how to get assertion if it is expired? If we re-initiate the SSO flow then assertion will be provided to the ACS (Assertion Consumer Service) URL which will cause a shifting from the current screen for an active user. This might cause an issue if the user has any unsaved activity on the page.

How can I provide an Assertion as a response to a request? Is there any provision in SAML for extending assertion directly via a single call to IDP?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "extend" an existing assertion, you'd have to ask IdP for a new one.

The workflow where a new token is requested via an existing assertion is rare but technically possible if you can hold on to the assertion after it's issued. Doing so would require an intermediate step/component between the IdP that issues the assertion and the oAuth client, something that is certainly possible in a number of solution architectures.

The refresh of an expired token via a new assertion would be a much more common implementation choice.